# lost ability to bind port 80 on mac, how to debug?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, docker, port

In the last few days I lost the ability to listen on port 80 with docker, and with nodejs without using sudo.

Before, I could simply launch my exact same docker containers on port 80, and it would bind to port 80. Now, it runs without error but doesn't actually listen on the port.

`sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "80"` doesnt show it.

I also used to be able to use node.js to listen on port 80 without sudo. Now, it gives the error error:

> listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80.

If I do sudo node myapp then it will listen like usual.

The only thing I can think of is some automated mac update or the fact that I installed virtualbox a few days ago.

How can I debug what's going on? I tried restarting. No difference. I've been using docker and node.js for years binding on port 80 and it stopped working randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In some operating systems, unprivileged users are prevented from binding on ports below a certain number to help prevent certain types of attacks.

I believe on Mac this behavior has changed over the years so perhaps it's changed again such as due to an update like you speculated.

One simple solution is to have it bind to a higher port number and then in your operating system firewall, set up a port forward from 80 to the higher port.